# Running a shell script in .vimrc (and processing the output)

Tags: vim, shell

I am trying to run a shell script from within a .vimrc file (three problems marked in the script):

```
function! CheckMe(file)
    let shellcmd = 'checkme '.a:file

    " Start the command and return 0 on success.
    " XXX: How do you evaluate the return code?
    execute '!'.shellcmd
    if !result
        return 0
    endif

    " Ending up here, the command returned an error.
    " XXX: Where to you get the output?
    let pair = split(output, '\S')
    let line = pair[0]
    let char = pair[1]

    " Jump to the errenous column and line.
    " XXX: Why does this not work?
    normal '/\%'.line.'l\%'.char.'c'
    return 1
endfunction
```

So to summarize, how do you get the result/output of the script, and why does the jump statement not work?

Additional details:

- The shell script returns 0 on success, and 1 on failure. On a failure, the script prints two numbers (line and column number) to stdout, separated by a space character.
- According to the [Vim docs](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/various.html#:normal), the argument of the "normal" keyword is "executed like it is typed", but apparently that is not the case. It works fine when I type it (in the normal command mode, without leading ':'), but doesn't in the script ("E78: Unknown mark).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
function! CheckMe(file)
    let shellcmd = 'checkme '.a:file

    let output=system(shellcmd)
    if !v:shell_error
        return 0
    endif

    " Are you sure you want to split on non-blanks? This 
    " will result in list of blank strings.
    " My variant:
    let [line, char]=split(output)

    " Normal is not an execute: this is what it will do:
    " «'/» means «Go to mark /», produces an error E78 because /
    " is not a valid symbol for mark. Than normal stops after error occured.
    " If you need to use variables in nomal use «execute 'normal '.ncmd».
    " And you can not use «normal» to perform search
    execute '/\%'.line.'l\%'.char.'c'
    " or
    call setpos('.', [0, line, char, 0])
    return 1
endfunction
```

> According to the Vim docs, the argument of the "normal" keyword is "executed like it is typed", but apparently that is not the case. It works fine when I type it (in the normal command mode, without leading ':'), but doesn't in the script ("E78: Unknown mark).

Just type «'/» to get this error.

Answer (score 7):

I think you want to use the [`system()` function](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#system()) instead of the `!` shell command.

From the linked page:

```
The result is a String.  Example:
            :let files = system("ls " .  shellescape(expand('%:h')))
```

and

```
The resulting error code can be found in |v:shell_error|.
```

So your `output` would come from the result of the system call and your `result` would come from `v:shell_error`. Then your jump should work.